# How to update internet browsers (firefox/chromium) on Ubuntu with Ubuntu Pro subscription

Tags: updates, firefox, chromium

I took advantage of the offer to use Ubuntu Pro subscription free for personal use, following this step by step guide: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-beta-tutorial/31018

After esm repository was added I received updates of over 220 packages on my 16.04 Ubuntu, which is very cool, that Canonical continues to support this version of Ubuntu.

```
pro security-status
1340 packages installed:
     1092 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
     234 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
     7 packages from third parties
     7 packages no longer available for download

To get more information about the packages, run
    pro security-status --help
for a list of available options.

Main/Restricted packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled until 2026. You have received 228 security
updates.

Universe/Multiverse packages are receiving security updates from
Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled until 2026. You have received 35 security
updates.
```

The only issue I have - I don't know how to update internet browsers - neither firefox nor chromium were updated.
Does anyone use Ubuntu Pro subscription on 16.04 LTS? How to update firefox/chromium packages?

Comment: Ubuntu Pro does *not* provide backports of Firefox to 'older' versions of the repositories.  If you are on a 32bit system your support is also limited.  You *need* to upgrade to a supported release.  Also, 16.04 is *offtopic* as it is beyond standard support periods here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firefox PPA by Mozilla, which supports i386 firefox for Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: Installing firefox snap package I get this:
`sudo snap install firefox
error: snap "firefox" is not available on stable for this architecture (i386) but exists on other
       architectures (amd64, arm64, armhf).`

Comment: I can install chromium snap package, but I get the error when I run it:
"Aw, snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. Error code: SIGSEGV" 
This happens on any page - no access to the internet.

Comment: From terminal:
`user@user:~$ chromium
[11166:11264:1024/041219.176428:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(642)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.189" (uid=1000 pid=11166 comm="/snap/chromium/1865/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)` 1st part

Comment: `[11166:11264:1024/041219.189556:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(642)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.190" (uid=1000 pid=11166 comm="/snap/chromium/1865/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom")` 2nd part

Comment: `interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
[11271:11271:1024/041219.284911:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.` the ending

Comment: I did not realize you are on a 32 bit system. See my updated answer.